# gitlab: Connection to UNKNOWN port -1: Broken pipe

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to connect to gitlab repository but get the error:

`banner exchange: Connection to UNKNOWN port -1: Broken pipe`

`fatal: Could not read from remote repository`

Interestingly, after some time this error disappears on its own and everything works fine

Comment: Although the extreme lack of actual information: it looks like there is a timeout in whatever command you are trying to perform, which could be because of an unstable network connection.